# How to server static assets on an Openshift NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, nginx, openshift

I am working on my NodeJS app hosted by Openshift. Everything works fine right now but I want to speed things up by serving static files (html, css, js) from a web server rather than doing it from Express. I've read somewhere that Node cartridges do not have an Apache server running, and thus no .htaccess file from where I can configure Apache to send my files.

How can I serve my static files from a web server like Apache or Nginx from my NodeJS app on Openshift?

Comment: ....why don't you just serve static files with node?

Answer (score 1):

This may suit your needs.  Bare as it gets static server...

```
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler')
var http = require('http')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

// Serve up public/ftp folder
var serve = serveStatic('public/', {'index': ['index.html']})

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var done = finalhandler(req, res)
    serve(req, res, done)
})

// Listen
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since the original question was posted, but maybe this will help other people facing the same issue. Have a look at this custom OpenShift cartridge here: https://github.com/gsterjov/openshift-nginx-cartridge

I haven't tested it personally, but I've built other custom cartridges and I know the OpenShift platform is quite flexible if you're proficient enough with the shell, so if the above cartridge doesn't suit your needs you can easily fork it and tweak it as you see fit.

Personally I'm almost always serving static assets from Node.js. The [built-in static server in Express.js](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) got so much better lately and there's also [st](https://github.com/isaacs/st) if you need more control over caching / etags.

Also, I've recently came across this interesting CDN-like alternative to "classic" hosting for static assets: http://surge.sh. I can imagine it would be fairly trivial to implement a gulp/grunt scenario for publishing your static assets on surge on deployment...